# Fix spacing in copycat program

Tags: c++, copy, spacing

Here is my code for a basic copycat program that just copys whatever the user types:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#include <string>

int main()
{
    cout << "type something.. I dare you..." << endl;
    for (;;)
    {
        string usrin;
        cout << "You: ";
        cin >> usrin;
        cout << "Me: " << usrin;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when the user inputs more than one word i get this:

> Me: more
>
> You: than
>
> You: Me: one
>
> You: Me: word
>
> You:

any and all help is appreciated! thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `cin.getline(usrin)` instead of `cin >> usrin`.

`cin >> usrin` stops reading when it finds whitespace characters in the stream but leaves the rest of the stream for the next time `cin` is used.

`cin.getline` will read until the end of the line. However, you will need to change `usrin` to an array of `char`.

```
char usrln[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
```

where MAX_LINE_LENGTH is a constant that is bigger than the length of the longest line you expect to see.

Comment: use cin.getline(usrin,max_line_length) with a previous char usrln[max_line_length] it worked! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

After each input, `\n` leaved behind in input buffer and read on next iteration. You need to flush your input buffer. Use

```
cin.ignore(MAX_INT, '\n'); //Ignores to the end of line
```

Add `<limits.h>` header.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "type something.. I dare you..." << endl;
    for (;;)
    {
        string usrin;
        cout << "You: ";
        cin >> usrin;
        cout << "Me: " << usrin ;//<<endl;
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm very new to programming... so bare with me.. but is this what your talking about? cin >> usrin >> "/n"; because i got an error when i tried that

Comment: No. Use what I suggested in answer.

Comment: it worked except now the program does not copy anything after the first word for example You: more than one word Me: more

Comment: @fluxD613; This is because `cin` reads up to white-space character only. When you input like  `more than one word` the only first word `more` will store in `usrin`. If you wanna read entire line then use `cin,getline()`.